# Dispay content based on dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm making a web app using mvc .net(c#) with a registration page. There are two types of users, lets call them type 1 and type 2. I'm my form I have a drowpdown list where they can choose their type. If the option for type 2 is selected I would like to display  an input for a pdf file. I don't have much experience with javascript or ajax so I was wondering if I can use one of them for this purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript is all you need, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) out for hiding elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your HTML looks like:

```html
<select name="user_type" id="user_type">
<option value="">Select User Type</option>
<option value="type_1">Type 1</option>
<option value="type_2">Type 2</option>
</select>


<!-- Where to show your result? -->
<div id="result"></div>

<!-- Load your jQuery script -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Your JavaScript

```js
// Provided that you have load your jQuery
$("#user_type").change(function()
{
   $.ajax({
   url:"page.asp", // The ASP page to fetch your user result
   type:"POST",
   data: {"user_type":$(this).val()},
   success: function(response)
   {
      //Success, display the result
      $("#result").html(response);
   },
   error: function(response)
   {
      //In case error occurs, handle your errors
      alert("Error occurs!"+response);
   }
   });
});
```

### Then in your ASP file:

Just retrieve the post DATA with the name `user_type`, then after your queries, print the result, this will be captured to the `response` parameter in the `success()` method of the ajax if the query is successful or in the `error()` method if the query is not successful.

Hope this helps!